# Some PHP Code Getting Executed -- Some Not

Tags: php

I have created a simple online user registration system. The user enters their information and it gets posted to a database and the user is sent an email to verify their account. The email contains a link to the verified.php page.

```
http://example.com/verified.php?id=22&h=6b530ee42cb25fdf7823ef393a58b68e
```

"id" is the new record number in the database.
"h" is a random hash that has been written to a field in the database.

The code in verified.php looks like this:

```
require("cDB.php");
$pass = 0;

//Read the Users table and retrieve the verification field for the given user
$db = new db();
$results = $db->query("SELECT Verification from Users WHERE UIdx=?",$_GET['id'])->fetchArray();

echo "pass1: " . $pass;
if($results['Verification'] == $_GET['h']) {
  echo "pass2: " . $pass;
  $db->query("UPDATE Users SET Verification='', Activated=1 WHERE UIdx=?",$_GET['id']);
  echo "pass3: " . $pass;
  $pass = 1;
}
echo "pass4: " . $pass;

if ($pass == 1) {
  echo "Success";
} else {
  echo "Failed";
}

?>
```

(I've placed a bunch of "echo" statements in the code for troubleshooting.)

When visited, the output of the page is:
pass1: 0
pass4: 0
Failed

At first glance one might think that the code inside the "if" block is not getting executed, but the database IS getting updated. When I view the record in the database, the Verification field is indeed empty and the Activated field has been changed from 0 to 1.

So the Update query is getting executed, but the rest of the code in the "if" block is not.

Thoughts?

SOLVED!
I'm not sure if this is a solution or a work around...I removed the Verification='' from the query. Essentially, comparison with the Verification field and the hash will now succeed every time. I will clear the Verification field when the user logs in for the first time.

I would like to understand why this code is being called multiple times. In one instance during troubleshooting, I noticed that the id and h were different than the original call.

Thank you for all your suggestions.

Comment: Try using `print_r($results);` as it may be that it's an array of records, so you may need to use `$results[0]['Verification']`

Comment: Sounds like the script somehow gets executed twice; the first time it updates the database and the second time it shows your results. How is this code being called, can you log the access to it?

Comment: On a side-note, beware: Once verified, an empty verification key would be accepted and might trigger a re-activation. Hackers could potentially use something like that to gain access to accounts.

Comment: Possibly this is getting fired twice.  First time the update occurs, the second time the output is what you are seeing.  Betware of non idempodent GETs.  Check your logs.  Could possibly be caused by a prefetch in the email client, or something else.

Comment: @Stratadox: This page/code is being called directly from the link in the email sent to the new user. There is no redirection of any kind.

Comment: Make sure you don't have incorrect rewrite rules that trigger the execution of this script for other requests like, f.e. `/favicon.ico`. Some browsers asks for `/favicon.ico` when you load the page, therefore they send two requests.

Comment: @Mardawn It could be some preflight request or other. Try and replace your echo's with writing to a log file somehow (file_put_contents can do the trick) & you'll get more insight in what happens. The underlying problem is probably the request method being get while doing a write, that tends to confuse clients because get method is a promise that they can call it multiple times

Comment: Based on some troubleshooting done in the answer below, the code (or at least parts of it) are being executed multiple times, with the results of the final execution being displayed on the page. Can you offer any explanation as to why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and we can debug more.  First in order to know what is going on var_dump is your friend.  Once you get more advanced I highly recommend XDebug.  Also make sure you are checking your variables are set before looking for their values.  It may not be set in some situations.

Also a good idea to sanitize your input.

```
<?php
require("cDB.php");
$debug = true;

$my_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$my_h = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'h', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
try {
    //Read the Users table and retrieve the verification field for the given user
    $db = new db();
    $results = $db->query("SELECT Verification from Users WHERE UIdx=?", $my_id)->fetchArray();

    if ($debug) {
        var_dump($results);
    }

    if (isset($results['Verification']) && $results['Verification'] == $my_h) {
        $updateStatus = $db->query("UPDATE Users SET Verification='', Activated=1 WHERE UIdx=?", $my_id);

        if ($debug) {
            var_dump("My Update Status : " . $updateStatus);
        }

    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Comment: The output of this code is: string(18) "My Results : Array"

Comment: I am also getting the following error in the error log: PHP Recoverable fatal error:               
       Object of class db could not be converted to string in /xxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/public_html/run/verified3.php on line 20       which is the var_dump for $updateStatus.

Comment: try again, had to remove the string.

Comment: Output is now: array(1) { ["Verification"]=> string(0) "" }   ...... I added file_put_contents('testing1.txt',"1",FILE_APPEND); after your var_dump($results) and verified that the code is being called multiple times. I ended up with three 1's in testing1.txt. WHY?

Comment: You are gonna have to use your answer to elaborate.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the request is somehow being processed twice. I'm not entirely sure what causes that; it could be a lot of things. What matters most here, though, is that you're using a http `GET` request method. This method is made for requesting ("getting") information, and is not supposed to change the server's state. A `GET` method is essentially a promise to the client (read: browser) that it's okay to call the route multiple times. ([Read more at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Safe_methods) or [W3](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html))

Since, in your case, multiple requests to the same route do not produce the same result both times (also known as "not idempotent") you're probably better off not promising to the browser that they can request it multiple times.

The most straightforward way of doing that in practice is by inserting a form in between. If you don't want to bother the user with a confirmation screen, you could consider automatically submitting it.